# fetch only returning results on second execution

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a React application and am adding a search page with a simple text box, search button, and (eventually) a list of results.  **The problem is** that when I enter text and click the button I get the console message "data: null" (first log details below).  Without refreshing the page, I simply enter the same text again, click the button, and the message is then "data: ALL OF THE JSON I WANT/EXPECT".  It has been surprisingly difficult to get everything to play nicely together.  Using [this code from a tutorial](https://github.com/samie820/hooks-movie-app/blob/master/src/components/App.js) I have attempted to move everything from simple useState to useReducer (which I still really can't fully grasp, ugh).  Below are the three files involved.  The only times I have strayed from the code in the link above were to move everything from App.js to ItemSearchForm.js which took a little maneuvering, and I'm using react-hook-form/useForm for the form rather than native `<form>`.

Can anyone help me understand why the first execution returns null and the second returns what I'm expecting?  Any other wisdom you can impart is also **definitely** welcome.  Thanks so much and happy holidays to all!

ItemSearch.js

```
import React, {
  useReducer,
  useState,
} from "react";
import {
  useForm,
  //Controller
} from "react-hook-form";

import { AppConfig } from "../../config/appConfig";
import {
  ItemSearchReducer,
  ItemSearchActions,
  ItemSearchInitialState,
} from "./ItemSearchReducer";
import ItemSearchForm from "./ItemSearchForm";
import { axios } from "axios";

const ItemSearch = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm();

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    ItemSearchReducer,
    ItemSearchInitialState
  );
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   async function doWork() {
  //     console.log("@ doWork()");
  //     await sleep(1500);
  //     console.log("waited 1500ms");
  //     let searchUrl = AppConfig.API_ROOT + generateSearchEndpointUrl(); // todo: string $interpolation$ maybe?
  //     await fetch(searchUrl, {
  //       method: "GET",
  //       headers: {
  //         "Content-Type": "application/json",
  //       },
  //     }).then((response) => {
  //       dispatch({
  //         type: ItemSearchActions.ITEM_SEARCH_SUCCESS,
  //         payload: response.json().items, // todo: maybe this should be response.json only so the metadata is included?
  //       });
  //     });
  //   }

  //   doWork();
  // }, []);

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  async function search(searchText) {
    console.log("@itemsSearch.js search() searchText: " + searchText);

    dispatch({
      type: ItemSearchActions.ITEM_SEARCH_REQUEST,
    });

    await sleep(1500);
    let searchUrl = AppConfig.API_ROOT + generateSearchEndpointUrl(searchText); // todo: string $interpolation$ maybe?
    console.log("searchUrl: " + searchUrl);
    await fetch(searchUrl, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));

    console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log("items: " + JSON.stringify(data?.items));
  }

  const { loading, items, errorMessage } = ItemSearchInitialState;

  const itemList =
    loading && !errorMessage ? (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    ) : errorMessage ? (
      <div>Error: {errorMessage}</div>
    ) : (
      items.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item.title}</div>)
    );

  return (
    <>
      <ItemSearchForm search={search} />
      <h2>Some Search Results</h2>
      <div>{itemList}</div>
    </>
  );

  function generateSearchEndpointUrl(searchTerm) {
    return `/itemSearch/itemSearch?searchstring=${searchTerm}`;
  }

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
};

export default ItemSearch;
```

ItemSearchReducer.js

```
export const ItemSearchInitialState = {
  loading: true,
  items: [],
  errorMessage: null,
};

export const ItemSearchActions = {
  ITEM_SEARCH_REQUEST: "ITEM_SEARCH_REQUEST",
  ITEM_SEARCH_SUCCESS: "ITEM_SEARCH_SUCCESS",
  ITEM_SEARCH_FAIL: "ITEM_SEARCH_FAIL",
  ITEM_SEARCH_NO_RESULTS: "ITEM_SEARCH_NO_RESULTS",
};

export const ItemSearchReducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log("@ ItemSearchReducer");
  console.log("action " + action);
  console.log("action.type " + action.type);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
  switch (action.type) {
    case ItemSearchActions.ITEM_SEARCH_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true, errorMessage: null };
    case ItemSearchActions.ITEM_SEARCH_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, items: action.payload };
    case ItemSearchActions.ITEM_SEARCH_FAIL:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.error };
    case ItemSearchActions.ITEM_SEARCH_NO_RESULTS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, items: [], error: action.error };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

ItemSearchForm.js (the component that ultimately is put on the page like

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const ItemSearchForm = ({ search }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm();
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  const handleSearchInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value);
  };

  const resetSearchText = () => {
    setSearchText("");
  };

  const callSearch = (e) => {
    console.log("running callSearch");
    console.log("searchText: " + searchText);
    e.preventDefault();
    search(searchText);
    resetSearchText();
  };

  const generateSearchBoxPlaceholder = () => {
    var searchStrings = [
      "title:jurassic author:michael",
      "dinosaurs published>2020-02-01",
      "comic book pages>100",
      "title:rich",
    ];
    return searchStrings[Math.floor(Math.random() * searchStrings.length)];
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={callSearch}>
        <Container>
          <Typography variant="h4" component="h2">
            Search for Somethin'
          </Typography>
          <Container>
            <TextField
              name="searchString"
              value={searchText} // value={searchTerm}
              inputRef={register} // todo: MUST FIX!
              label="Search"
              placeholder={generateSearchBoxPlaceholder()}
              onChange={handleSearchInputChange}
              fullWidth
              autoComplete="off"
            />
          </Container>
        </Container>

        {/* <FormControlLabel control={<Controller as={Checkbox} control={control} name="checkboxname" color="primary" defaultValue={false} />}
      label="the checkbox" /> */}

        <Container>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            //   disabled={submitting} // todo: disable button when submitting
            color="primary"
          >
            Search
          </Button>
        </Container>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default ItemSearchForm;
```

Log from first execution:

```
ItemSearchForm.js:36 running callSearch
ItemSearchForm.js:37 searchText: d
ItemSearch.js:67 @itemsSearch.js search() searchText: d
ItemSearchReducer.js:15 @ ItemSearchReducer
ItemSearchReducer.js:16 action [object Object]
ItemSearchReducer.js:17 action.type ITEM_SEARCH_REQUEST
ItemSearchReducer.js:18 {"loading":true,"items":[],"errorMessage":null}
ItemSearch.js:77 searchUrl: https://localhost:5001/api/itemSearch/itemSearch?searchstring=d
ItemSearch.js:78 Fetch finished loading: GET "https://localhost:5001/api/itemSearch/itemSearch?searchstring=d".
ItemSearch.js:101 data: null
```

Log from second execution

```
ItemSearchForm.js:36 running callSearch
ItemSearchForm.js:37 searchText: d
ItemSearch.js:67 @itemsSearch.js search() searchText: d
ItemSearchReducer.js:15 @ ItemSearchReducer
ItemSearchReducer.js:16 action [object Object]
ItemSearchReducer.js:17 action.type ITEM_SEARCH_REQUEST
ItemSearchReducer.js:18 {"loading":true,"items":[],"errorMessage":null}
ItemSearch.js:77 searchUrl: https://localhost:5001/api/itemSearch/itemSearch?searchstring=d
ItemSearch.js:78 Fetch finished loading: GET "https://localhost:5001/api/itemSearch/itemSearch?searchstring=d".
ItemSearch.js:101 data: {"resultCount":9,"items":[{"itemId":72, ... ETC ETC
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the setState is async and you have access to the actual value that you have set in the next render but you are logging it before you can have the new value.

Comment: The setData() in the last piece of the fetch()?  I don't have a setState per se (though I get the gist).  Simply removing all `await` and `async` isn't doing the trick.

Comment: By that, I meant ```setData``` that you have in your code. Any ```setState``` function in react is async and it doesn't work like that you have access to the updated value after the next render. Also you have two variables named ```data``` in your code try to change the name in ```fetch``` or the name of the state.